# Can not set form value to string if matDatepicker is set

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-datepicker

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

If I set the input value to a date everything works fine.

```
this.form.controls['date'].setValue(new Date());
```

[image]

But I also want to manully set the input value to a string like this

```
this.form.controls['date'].setValue('permanent');
```

But MatDatepicker does not allow me to do that and shows nothing (it probably expects a date format) even though my form accepts the string value 'permanent'.
form:

[image]

input:

[image]

What I was expecting:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Result

[image: after use custom date adapter]

By default, the mat-datepicker is using [`NativeDateAdapter`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/core/datetime/native-date-adapter.ts) as the default `DateAdapter`.

You can create a custom date adapter class by extending from `DateAdapter`.

For example, I created `custom-date-adapter.ts` and extend `DateAdapter` with type param `<Date | string>` which allow support of `string`.

```typescript
export class CustomDateAdapter extends DateAdapter<Date | string> {
```

Inject and use the default `NativeDateAdapter` when overriding `DateAdapter` abstract methods

```typescript
  adapter: NativeDateAdapter;
  ...
  constructor(nativeDateAdapter: NativeDateAdapter) {
  ...
      this.adapter = nativeDateAdapter;
```

For example, for `parse` and `isDateInstance` override, check for `permanent` keyword, if true, then return. Else, call the `nativeDateAdapter` default method.

[`NativeDateAdapter@isDateInstance`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/962c9a381f68f911fd5be29ff3cefd2edd7b5efe/src/material/core/datetime/native-date-adapter.ts#L206) is called when `setValue('permanent')`

and

[`NativeDateAdapter@parse`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/962c9a381f68f911fd5be29ff3cefd2edd7b5efe/src/material/core/datetime/native-date-adapter.ts#L128) is called when type in`permanent`.

```typescript
  parse(value: any, parseFormat: any): string | Date | null {
    if (value === 'permanent') {
      return 'permanent';
    }
    return this.adapter.parse(value, parseFormat);
  }
  isDateInstance(obj: any): boolean {
    if (obj === 'permanent') {
      return true;
    }
    return this.adapter.isDateInstance(obj);
  }
```

Other small details like the `private _today: Date = new Date();`, this variable is used in other override methods, to pass into `nativeDateAdapter` method when the user enters any `string`, so that the date picker can expand and point to today date.

For example, if return `0` in `getYear` method, the picklist will point to 0 years when the user enters string input and expand it.

---

### Full code

### app.component.html

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

  <hr>

  date.value = {{ form.controls['date'].value }}

  <br/>

  date.valid = {{ form.controls['date'].valid }}
</form>
```

### app.component.ts

```typescript
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ng-date-picker';
  form = new FormGroup({
    date: new FormControl('permanent')
  });
}
```

### app.module.ts

```typescript
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {
  DateAdapter,
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MAT_DATE_FORMATS,
  MAT_NATIVE_DATE_FORMATS,
  NativeDateAdapter,
} from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { CustomDateAdapter } from './custom-date-adapter';

import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    NativeDateAdapter,
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: CustomDateAdapter },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

### custom-date-adapter.ts

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  DateAdapter, NativeDateAdapter
} from '@angular/material/core';

@Injectable()
export class CustomDateAdapter extends DateAdapter<Date | string> {
  adapter: NativeDateAdapter;
  private _today: Date = new Date();

  constructor(nativeDateAdapter: NativeDateAdapter) {
    super();
    this.adapter = nativeDateAdapter;
  }

  parse(value: any, parseFormat: any): string | Date | null {
    if (value === 'permanent') {
      return 'permanent';
    }
    return this.adapter.parse(value, parseFormat);
  }
  isDateInstance(obj: any): boolean {
    if (obj === 'permanent') {
      return true;
    }
    return this.adapter.isDateInstance(obj);
  }
  isValid(date: string | Date): boolean {
    return date instanceof Date
      ? this.adapter.isValid(date)
      : date === 'permanent';
  }
  getYear(date: string | Date): number {
    return date instanceof Date
      ? this.adapter.getYear(date)
      : this.adapter.getYear(this._today);
  }
  getMonth(date: string | Date): number {
    return date instanceof Date
      ? this.adapter.getMonth(date)
      : this.adapter.getMonth(this._today);
  }
  getDate(date: string | Date): number {
    return date instanceof Date
      ? this.adapter.getDate(date)
      : this.adapter.getDate(this._today);
  }
  getDayOfWeek(date: string | Date): number {
    return date instanceof Date
      ? this.adapter.getDayOfWeek(date)
      : this.adapter.getDayOfWeek(this._today);
  }
  getMonthNames(style: 'long' | 'short' | 'narrow'): string[] {
    return this.adapter.getMonthNames(style);
  }
  getDateNames(): string[] {
    return this.adapter.getDateNames();
  }
  getDayOfWeekNames(style: 'long' | 'short' | 'narrow'): string[] {
    return this.adapter.getDayOfWeekNames(style);
  }
  getYearName(date: string | Date): string {
    return date instanceof Date
      ? this.adapter.getYearName(date)
      : this.adapter.getYearName(this._today);
  }
  getFirstDayOfWeek(): number {
    return this.adapter.getFirstDayOfWeek();
  }
  getNumDaysInMonth(date: string | Date): number {
    return date instanceof Date
      ? this.adapter.getNumDaysInMonth(date)
      : this.adapter.getNumDaysInMonth(this._today);
  }
  clone(date: string | Date): string | Date {
    return date instanceof Date
      ? this.adapter.clone(date)
      : this.adapter.clone(this._today);
  }
  createDate(year: number, month: number, date: number): string | Date {
    return this.adapter.createDate(year, month, date);
  }
  today(): string | Date {
    return this.adapter.today();
  }
  format(date: string | Date, displayFormat: any): string {
    return date instanceof Date
      ? this.adapter.format(date, displayFormat)
      : (date as string);
  }
  addCalendarYears(date: string | Date, years: number): string | Date {
    return date instanceof Date
      ? this.adapter.addCalendarYears(date, years)
      : '';
  }
  addCalendarMonths(date: string | Date, months: number): string | Date {
    return date instanceof Date
      ? this.adapter.addCalendarMonths(date, months)
      : '';
  }
  addCalendarDays(date: string | Date, days: number): string | Date {
    return date instanceof Date ? this.adapter.addCalendarDays(date, days) : '';
  }
  toIso8601(date: string | Date): string {
    return date instanceof Date ? this.adapter.toIso8601(date) : '';
  }
  invalid(): string | Date {
    return this.adapter.invalid();
  }
}
```

### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "ng-date-picker",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  }
}
```